# package-lock, package.json, woe

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm not a node expert by any means. In one project, something's gone wrong somewhere, and package-lock.json and package.json seems to have fallen out of sync. The only way I can get stuff to build is this sequence:

`rm -rf node-modules
npm install
rm package-lock.json
npm install
webpack`

i.e. I have to run npm install once with package-lock, and then once without. There are a lot of dependencies, and tracking down which ones are needed is proving difficult. What's the best way of resolving this so that I don't need to npm install twice? And how can I prevent this sort of thing not arising in the future?

Note: Two different devs were working on this git repo, and it's very possible that the package-lock and package files were not checked in properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was to do with a specific version of @types/react-redux. There's a breaking change between 4.4.40, and 4.4.41. I was previously using ^4.4.40, so when the package-lock was being used, it was fetching 4.4.40, and everything worked. When I deleted the package lock, the ^4.4.40 moniker downloaded 4.4.41, as it was latest, and things broke. Changing the version from ^4.4.40 to just 4.4.40 has fixed it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Could You paste Your packake.json and package-lock.json files here?

If they are too big - put them in some fillde and give link.

(srry that this is an answer, not a comment, but don't have 50 rep needed).